# In Lua, how can I tell if a number divides evenly into another number?

Tags: math, lua, division, coronasdk

In Lua, how can I tell if a number divides evenly into another number? i.e with no remainder? I'm just looking for a boolean true or false.

```
12/6 = 2 (true)
18/6 = 3 (true)
20/6 = 3.(3) (false)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Compare the remainder of the division to zero, like this:

```
12 % 6 == 0

18 % 6 == 0

20 % 6 ~= 0
```

The modulus operator (`%`) returns the remainder of division. For 12 and 6 it is 0, but for 20 and 6 it is 2.

The formula it uses is: `a % b == a - math.floor(a/b)*b`

Comment: The cool thing about % is that it works on real numbers as well

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the modulus operator is, it doesn't work correctly on negative numbers. If you're going to be using negative numbers, use `math.fmod` instead:

```
maxtothemax@maxtothemax-mint ~ $ lua 
> return  -13%6
5
> return  13%6
1
> return math.fmod (-13, 6)
-1
> return math.fmod (13, 6)
1
>
```

Comment: For comparisons to 0, the modulus operator appears to work fine. No need to make an extra function call.

Comment: Whether `-13 % 6 == 5` is incorrect a matter of opinion. This is often the behaviour you want.